# Deploying through Azure Resource Group project

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-powershell, azure-deployment

I created a web deploy package of Web Api through "msbuild" power shell command and placed it in artifacts location of Azure resource group project.

When I try to deploy it throws error in "New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment" in Deploy_AzureResourceGroup script.

But when I try to deploy a same package created through visual studio it works fine and gets deployed succesfully.

Both web deploy packages has got same files and error thrown doesnt has any information
Below is the error I got which is a generic error and not related to package:

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 13:13:29 - Resource 
Microsoft.Web/sites/extensions 'WebAppui/MSDeploy' failed 
with message 'The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning 
state 'Failed'.'
At .....\azureresourcegroup\Scripts\Deploy-AzureResourceG
roup.ps1:101 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ((Get-ChildItem 
$TemplateFile).BaseName ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeplo 
   yment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCommand

Comment: What kind of error does it throw though?

Comment: Share your error message.

Comment: Added the error above

Comment: Most of the time this has to do with AzureRM not being able to find or access the webdeploy package (the error thrown is not at all helpful as you can see).  One thing you can try is adding the -Debug switch to the New-AzureRMResourceGroupDeployment cmdlets.  This will dump the raw http conversation from AzureRM and you might get a "real" error message instead of the one from the -Verbose output.  There is a lot in the debug output so you have to hunt carefully for the error.

Comment: Even in debug mode the error thrown is exactly same and I couldn't get more information on exactly where it went wrong.

Comment: How do you package your web deploy file? Are you able to share the basic structure of your web deploy package?

Comment: I packages it through msbuild command, basic structure is same for both package(i.e through visual studio build), only difference is the size which is slightly larger in msbuild package because of bin folders